# Sending emails from Django App

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email, smtp, sendgrid

We are a growing Django app that is currently using Google Apps to send email. We are hitting the maximum limits of email sending and need a better solution. We prefer not to have to manage our own email servers and the easier the better. What is the best, easiest, and cheapest way to send a large amount of email?

- We have looked at Postageapp but they require you to use your own SMTP server.
- We are considering App Engine to send email but it will require a lot of configuration to get it to work correctly.

What can we use to quickly fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what you want: http://sendgrid.com/ :)

Comment: disclaimer: I work at SendGrid ... check out our sendgrid-python library on github (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python), I use it in a "sendgrid-django" sample project you can get from here: https://github.com/iandouglas/sendgrid-django

Answer (score 2):

http://postmarkapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to get a beta invitation atm, and I haven't used it myself, but I like the looks of [CritSend](http://www.critsend.com/).

Hopefully we'll see more competition for services like this and I wish I'd discovered it before going through all the hassles of trying to get a domain cleared for delivery into hotmail, yahoo, etc. (this goes beyond just adding spf/domainkeys to your DNS).

Answer (score 0):

Django includes the functionality of sending emails https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/, try including this in `settings.py`:

```
# Email configuration.

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Of course, you can change the gmail smtp server for any other. If you want to use your `domain.com` instead of `gmail.com`, that is also possible.
Hope it help, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

We are using currently Amazon SES which has 10000 / 24hrs. We haven't reached that limit yet and we already have few thousand users posting content [which triggers emails].
You can request more.

The best way to manage your volume is to actually consolidate emails instead of sending email on every event. for e.g. if a user's post gets comments from 5 different people, we send that as one email and also every top of hours. its not instantaneous but the users are very happy about receiving it that form. 
This reduced our volume drastically.

Anyway, sendgrid is also an excellent mail service.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid is now a partner with Google App Engine and Google Compute Cloud and you can sign up for a free account that will give you 25,000 messages per month instead of the old 200/day (~6000 per month)